# Develop an Application with more than one programming language

Tags: programming-languages

I have a question that was bugging me for a while, sorry if it is rookie question:
Is there a way to develop an application with more than one programming language?
Today i was looking for a Video Player in Linux and i saw this:

> MPV Player: Written in C, Objective-C, Lua and Python, MPV is...

Can anyone explain how they write an application in multiple language?
Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the ability to call a function written in one language (and implementation) from a function written in another one (and its implementation).

The [lua](http://lua.org/) scripting language (and interpreter) was designed to be easily embeddable in C applications. Read the chapter [*The Application Program Interface*](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4) of Lua manual (Lua uses some stack for arguments and results). And [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) is also designed to be easily embeddable, and has a nice [tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/docs/guile-tut/tutorial.html) explaining that (you give the arity of your foreign functions to the Guile runtime).

Sometimes, you need to follow specific conventions (which depends upon the *implementation*) to call a [foreign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface). For examples, Python has a chapter on [Extending and Embedding The Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/index.html); C++ code need to annotate with `extern "C"` the declaration of functions coded in C (or callable from C), Ocaml's manual has a chapter about [Interfacing C with Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html), etc.

More generally, be aware of [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and of [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s. Sometimes, you might want to use [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) which enables you to call functions of signature known only at runtime.

BTW, [MPV](https://mpv.io/) is open-source, so why don't you study its [source code](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/)?

Comment: Thank you very much, I read Extending and Embedding The Python Interpreter Link and it was amazing, i didn't know you can do this. Can you tell me that can i this process with Qt and Python?

Comment: No, you need to read documentation and experiment. I won't spend hours on that.

Comment: answer of your last question is easy: i couldn't, sorry don't mean to trouble you, i didn't mean that you tell me how, just that is it possible?